# Error 403 Access Forbidden XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, http-status-code-403, htdocs

I've tried everything, so I am forced to create this post.

I have changed the htdocs folder permissions

```
sudo chmod 644 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/
```

I have changed the httpd.conf file replacing a daemon by my user:

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User amldesign
Group daemon
</IfModule>
```

This happened from one day to the next...

what's happening here?

Comment: 1) Folder owner also can be root. Execute `ls -l` in your htdocs folder and look at user.
2) Execute `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` to look, who is current running user of web server.

Comment: This is unclear. What happened without your intervention, and what did you change exactly.

Comment: Mmmm if I run a grunt server by the port 3000 works fine, localhost:3000 its ok, but only localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: I can access creating a hostname, for example, mywebsite.dev 127.0.0.1